# Data transfer from a view from one database to a table in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am just trying to find out whether this is the right way to do this task.
Any other suggestions to improve this is greatly appreciated.

I have the following on my SSIS package.

[image]

1. Data Flow task and established a OLE DB connection to the source database where the view is.
2. Execute SQL task - I am executing a query with a INSERT INTO Destination Except (all those records that are already there from the source.)
3. Send mail task is to send out an email.

How to know that the data transfer is successful? So that I can use the send mail to
indicate success or failure.

How to schedule this package so that it runs automatically (Every Tuesday.)

I have tried the suggestion below. Please refer to the new Data Flow task.

[image]

OLE DB Source - Points to a view in database server 1
Lookup gets all the rows from OLE DB source. (the rowcount on source and on the lookup)
matches.

On the lookup task, I have configured error output to use 'Redirect row' on all the mapped columns.

On the OLE DB Destination (Destination table where it already has a subset of records from the source. So the Configured Error  output to get unmatches rows for insert.

When, I execute the package - I am getting an Primary key constraint error as - Cannot insert duplicate key.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to double click the connector from the `Execute SQL Task` to `Send Mail Task` Currently it's green which indicates it will only take that path on Success. You will want to update the constraint to be on Completion as you don't care if it's Success or Fail.

It sounds like you have your data flow pulling all of the data from your source and writing to a staging table. In your Execute SQL Task, you then use a query to add data into your target table where it doesn't exist.

This can be consolidated into a single Data Flow. Between your OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination, add a Lookup task. Since you are on 2005, the Lookup behaves a bit differently than 2008+. You will write a query that pulls back the business keys in your target table and then compares that to what is coming from your OLE DB Source. Map those keys in the interface.

You only want the rows that aren't matched so you will need to get the "unmatched records" from the lookup. In 2005, the option for Unmatched output didn't exist so you will need to route the Error output to your OLE DB Destination.

Andy Leonard has a nice little writeup on how to accomplish this: [Configuration an SSIS 2005 Lookup Transformation for a Left Outer Join](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2010/02/09/ssis-snack-configuring-an-ssis-2005-lookup-transformation-for-a-left-outer-join.aspx) The only difference for your case, is that you don't care about the matched rows. Instead of `Ignore Failure`, you want to select `Redirect Row`. Then when you go to connect the Lookup to the OLE DB Destination, you will be presented with two options. The Green Connector is the Matched, Red Connector is the Unmatched rows. Tie the Red path to your Destination

Comment: Thanks!! Inside the Data Flow tab - I now have a OLE DB Source (Source database  and data from View) , Look Up (looks up the view data from the source), and OLE DB Destination (contains destination database and table) - Because this SSIS package will be executed every week, I only want unmatched records to be transferred. I couldn't understand the "Route the error output to your OLE DB Destination." Any example of links that would help me configure this would be great. I appreciate your support.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the article. I am still having problems with this. When you mention "You will write a query that pulls back the business keys in your target table and then compares that to what is coming from your OLE DB Source. Map those keys in the interface" How do I achieve this? I am able to get the source and the look up task to compile (displays in green) and the destination is failing because of the primary key constraint. I am doing the Lookup Error output from look up to OLE DB destination. I apologize, if this is still vague. I greatly appreciate your support.

Comment: I have millions of records so each time, I execute this, I am taking atleast 2 hours. I had a thread issue, so increased the caching size to 250  MB to solve that issue. I got one more error and I used the "Restore Invalid Column References Editor" And I think, I did "Map invalid column references to available columns using column names".

Comment: The source is one database server and the destinatio is in another database server. Can I create two connection managers for one Lookup task?